# Trigger when update, insert, delete inventory

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to create a trigger for updating and inserting my Inventoryset table.

When the quantity is changed and it is less than 0 then I want Instock in my table ProductSet be changed, and if quantity is greater than 0.

My attempt does not work at all.

```
-- Creating table 'ProductSet'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductSet] (
    [ProductId] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [ImagePath] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] float  NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] int  NOT NULL,
    [InStock] bit  NOT NULL
);
GO


-- Creating table 'InventorySet'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InventorySet] (
    [InventoryId] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] int  NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO
```

I know this is wrong, but here you go. :P

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TestTrigger]
ON [dbo].[InventorySet]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF (SELECT dbo.InventorySet.Quantity) > 0 
    THEN INSERT INTO dbo.ProductSet (InStock) VALUE (1)
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO dbo.ProductSet (InStock) VALUE (2)
END
GO
```

This is what I have now:

```
-- Initierar databasen
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[InStockTrigger]
ON [dbo].[InventorySet]
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @Quantity BIT
SELECT @Quantity = dbo.InventorySet.Quantity FROM dbo.InventorySet

IF @Quantity > 0 
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO dbo.ProductSet (InStock) VALUES (1)
END
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO dbo.ProductSet (InStock) VALUES (2)         
END
GO
```

But when I add this, I want it to update the InStock (as I wrote my trigger for) but it don't.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT InventorySet ON
insert into InventorySet (InventoryId, Quantity, ProductId) values (1, 25, 1);
insert into InventorySet (InventoryId, Quantity, ProductId) values (2, 31, 2);
insert into InventorySet (InventoryId, Quantity, ProductId) values (3, 2, 3);
insert into InventorySet (InventoryId, Quantity, ProductId) values (4, 0, 4);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT InventorySet OFF
GO
```

Instead I get this error:

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure InStockTrigger, Line 309
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProductName', table 'ModelFirst.SupplementStore.dbo.ProductSet'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: That's a rather confusing design, IMO (what does it mean if there are multiple rows for the same `ProductId` in `InventorySet` and one has `Quantity` > 0 and another had `Quantity` < 0) - it's usually better to calculate things like this `InStock` value dynamically based on the data then available, rather than relying on triggers to maintain it. If you always rely on the *actual* data in `InventorySet`, you'll never be wrong/inconsistent. Only if this exposes a performance issue would I consider introducing this indicator (but I'd look to see whether it could be implemented without triggers)

Answer (score 0):

You are using after Insert,Update. After only fires after the insert runs, instead of fires instead of the insert or delete so you have access to the Insert/Delete tables incase you need them

You need to use [INSTEAD OF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). [Sql Server Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/24/sql-server-how-to-use-instead-of-trigger-guest-post-by-vikas-munjal-koenig-solutions/) has a better blog post about it imo

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TestTrigger]
ON [dbo].[InventorySet]
INSTEAD INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

--    NOW CHECK IF YOU HAVE the instock quantity that you want and do your magic. If you post your
--    table schema I could help with THAT

```
GO
```

Comment: I tried it, look at my edit I just did. Can you see what's wrong? :/

Comment: Your schema says you cannot insert a null value into productset. You need to post your schema, it looks like your pretty new to SQL you need to insert values into columns that are not nullable